# View PDF in Ubuntu Server edition ( CLI mode )

Tags: linux, command-line, pdf

To force myself to use CLI all the time, I've installed Ubuntu Server edition on my work laptop. However, I still want to be able to view PDF ( rendered as normal PDF, not converted to text ). Basically I want a totally CLI environment, except for PDF viewer.

Is this possible? How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you expect to run a PDF viewer in, if not within a graphical environment?

Comment: I dont mind temporary graphical environment, when the viewer is running.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just install the basic parts and call `startx` whenever you need to view a pdf.  Then exit and get back to the shell.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-core xauth xorg
```

See [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=RoT8nuzZY6MC&pg=PA77&lpg=PA77&dq=ubuntu+gnome+without+gdm&source=bl&ots=fZrQhDVn7v&sig=-PlxXmsgz_BRJXEkh6Yi33WGhoc&hl=en&ei=WUhOTtXBFqPo0QHbg5WiBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=10&ved=0CGgQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=ubuntu%20gnome%20without%20gdm&f=false) for a reference.